# Wolfram Workbench Notebook Launch failure

Tags: workbench

For the first time I attempted to open a Wolfram Notebook file from within Eclipse and I'm given a large error message from Java simultaneously generating a text file on my Desktop and closing Eclipse. I see **absolutely** no reason for this to be happening. How do I successfully launch the Wolfram Workbench?

What I have installed:

- Wolfram Mathematica 11.2
- Oracle Java SE 10
- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a);
  Build id: 20180405-1200; OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32)
- Wolfram Workbench (v. 10.1.822)

Within Eclipse:

Window>Preferences>Wolfram>Configured Installations: `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2`

Comment: I have seen something similar, but only right-clicking on a notebook and the executing "Run As Wolfram" : Eclipse crashes. But I attributed this to low memory available on (old) hardware. I tried to change the settings in eclipse.ini, unsuccessfully.

Comment: Also: How do you "open a Wolfram notebook" ? Try to do right  mouseclick and then select "Open with System Editor" (assuming that you set the default handler for .nb to Mathematica 11.2).

Comment: BTW: With the same Ecplise build (for Java, but that should not matter) I see no crashes with 10.1.822 on Window 10 (on two computers with 16 and 32 GB RAM ).

Comment: @RolfMertig From within Eclipse:  `File>Open file...` then I double click the file from the directory.

Comment: My computer has 8 GB RAM.

Comment: That should be enough.

Comment: It began to work after I added Java to my system path, `Environment Variables`.

Answer (score 1):

Find and edit the eclipse.ini, make sure to backup the original in case. Open the file with a text editor and put

"-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll" 
without the quotes

--launcher.appendVmargs 
{Insert Here} 
-vmargs

Note: check if jvm.dll is on the same path otherwise search it in windows

I have Mathematica 11.2, Eclipse Photon and Java JDK and JRE 10.0.1

Hope this helps you. I got mine working now with no problems.